# random.shuffle returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x

random.shuffle() returns None, can i get a shuffled value instead?

```
import random

testlist1 = ["1", "2"]
testlist2 = ["1a", "1b"]
testlist3 = ["2a", "2b"]

def generator(testlist1, testlist2, testlist3):
    genwords = ([random.choice(testlist1), random.choice(testlist2), random.choice(testlist3)])
    shufflegen = random.shuffle(genwords)
    print(shufflegen)

generator(testlist1, testlist2, testlist3)
```

Debug:

```
None
```

Comment: Maybe you want [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: I'd avoid naming your function simply `generator` as that word has a special meaning in Python https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator

Answer (score 2):

random.shuffle doesn't return a new list.
It shuffle the list you passed in place.

genwords is shuffled in your case.
Print genwords.
(And you may want to copy it before shuffling, if you needed it unshuffled)

```py
import random

testlist1 = ["1", "2"]
testlist2 = ["1a", "1b"]
testlist3 = ["2a", "2b"]

def generator(testlist1, testlist2, testlist3):
    genwords = ([random.choice(testlist1), random.choice(testlist2), random.choice(testlist3)])
    random.shuffle(genwords)
    print(genwords)

generator(testlist1, testlist2, testlist3)
```

Comment: Why did you leave `shufflegen =` in the code?  It's not just useless, it's distracting.

Comment: Indeed. I just copied the original code, and replace the print argument. But ideed. So edited.

Answer (score 0):

random.shuffle performs inplace shuffling.
Your code becomes:

```
import random

testlist1 = ["1", "2"]
testlist2 = ["1a", "1b"]
testlist3 = ["2a", "2b"]

def generator(testlist1, testlist2, testlist3):
    genwords = ([random.choice(testlist1), random.choice(testlist2), random.choice(testlist3)])
    random.shuffle(genwords)
    print(genwords)

generator(testlist1, testlist2, testlist3)
```